# How to "blockify" an object, and separate each block

Tags: modeling, workflow

How would one go around turning an already existing object into blocks, for a classic destruction-by-giant-ball animation? I've searched around quite a bit, but I can't really find this info anywhere. At this point I've used the remesh modifier in 'blocks' mode, but I don't really know where to go from here.[image]

Comment: You're probably looking for something like fracturing tools: https://youtu.be/wJFE2pb0Ri4?t=12s . Check out these references: (A) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DEo_9AopfoQ . (B) https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Object/Fracture